# Challenge unlocking a list of objects in my logic

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits, approval-process, locking

I am trying to using `Approval` class to lock and unlock records of an object `xyz__c`. When I run the below code I still see the record as locked and
unable to perform update on it:

```
List<xyz__c> unlocklist = new List<xyz__c>();

// some code which queries xyz__c records and checks whether it is locked or not
// and adds it to unlocklist if it is locked.
List<xyz__c> toupsertrecords =new List<xyz__c>();

 If(!unlocklist.isEmpty()){
 Approval.unlock(unlocklist, false);
     For(xyz__c pi : unlocklist){
           if(Approval.islocked(pi)){
           system.debug('It is locked =====>'); // this statement executes

           }
           // Approval.unlock(pi) - record gets updated if I have this here
       toupsertrecords.add(pi);   
     }
 }

 upsert toupsertrecords; // fails saying records are locked.
```

I had to use `Approval.unlock(pi)` inside the for loop to `upsert` the record successfully. This would hit governor limits if I put `Approval.unlock()` method inside the for loop.

However to see what is going wrong I ran the below command in my execute anonymous which gave me just opposite(expected) result:

```
List<id> listids = new List<id>{'a2QW0000000rAK9','a2QW0000000rBdB','a2QW0000000rBdR'};
List<xyz__c> pc=[select id from xyz__c where Id In:listids];
Approval.unlock(pc,false);
List<xyz__c> toupdate = new List<xyz__c>();
For(xyz__c p : pc){
    if(Approval.isLocked(p)){
        system.debug('It is locked =======================>');
    }else{
        system.debug('Not locked =======================>'); // this log gets executed
    }
    p.status__C = ' test';
    toupdate.add(p);
}
Approval.lock(pc,false);
```

This is surprising to me as now I am not sure why it executes fine from execute anonymous but not from my Apex class.

**Update**
After investigating the result using :

```
Approval.UnlockResult[] results = Approval.unlock(unlockList, false); 
for(Approval.UnlockResult result: results) { 
if(!result.issuccess()) 
{ system.debug(result.geterrors()[0].getmessage()); } 
}
```

The error says - `insufficient access rights on object id`.This is because the current user who is trying to update the record cannot update the record when in approval process. To over come this error I had to enable 'modify all' permission on the user's profile. I cannot give modify all permission though and need to figure out any other way. However a strange thing I noticed is the user is able to unlock the record if the record is unlocked in the for loop instead

```
 For(xyz__c pi : unlocklist){
       if(Approval.islocked(pi)){
       system.debug('It is locked =====>'); // this statement executes

       }
       Approval.unlock(pi) // record gets updated if I have this here
   toupsertrecords.add(pi);   
 }
```

Any comments about this?

Comment: You'll want to check the return value to determine why there was an error: `Approval.UnlockResult[] results = Approval.unlock(unlockList, false); for(Approval.UnlockResult result: results) { if(!result.issuccess()) { system.debug(result.geterrors()[0].getmessage()); } }`

Comment: I got `insufficient access rights on object id` when I use a list to unlock it( checked it from your above piece of code) , however why do I not get the same error when I unlock the record individually is a question now. Make sense?